# Get the client's IP address in socket.io

Tags: node.js, ip-address, socket.io

When using socket.IO in a Node.js server, is there an easy way to get the IP address of an incoming connection? I know you can get it from a standard HTTP connection, but socket.io is a bit of a different beast.

Comment: Slight tangent, but console.cat(socket) might possibly have helped by recursively dumping everything in the socket object onto the console

Comment: @izb Good point, but `console.dir(socket)` might be what you meant

Comment: For Socket 4.2.0+ the solutions doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Okay, as of 0.7.7 this is available, but not in the manner that lubar describes. I ended up needing to parse through some commit logs on git hub to figure this one out, but the following code does actually work for me now:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var address = socket.handshake.address;
  console.log('New connection from ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});
```

Comment: +1 thanks mate, do you perhaps know how i could get the remote address - or rather originating address? Right now its just logging the forward off my router.

Comment: Um... because his is .connection.remoteAddress and mine is .handshake.address?

Comment: And still working at 0.9.13
I'm getting the IP with socket.handhsake.address.address with no problems.

Thank you!

Comment: It's yielding me the client's local lan address.

Comment: @GarciadelCastillo you are behind a proxy probably. try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11187053/971459

Comment: Does not work in v1.0 — it just logs the address of the host for me.

Comment: this is the only thing that's worked for me, io v0.9 - logs client's web IP

Comment: As of version `1.3.7`, this returns `::ffff:127.0.0.1`

Comment: In version 1.3.7 this works great.  I am using this to track reconnects as i keep track of my own sockets myself.  socket.request.connection.remoteAddress works until the device stops responding and then it goes to undefined.  Also damn07 is getting a loopback address whether he uses either approach which likely means he is testing the system locally

Comment: `socket.request.connection.remoteAddress` for 1.x version

Comment: `socket.conn.transport.socket._socket.remoteAddress` for 2.0

Comment: I tried this on my local PC, But i receive `New connection from undefined:undefined`

Answer (score 79):

for 1.0.4:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var socketId = socket.id;
  var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;

  console.log(clientIp);
});
```

Comment: Where did you get the info?  I thought I had read all the docs for socket.io and did not see this.  It worked perfectly to solve my problems similar to the OP.

Comment: Just console.log socket to view all of the available information, I believe it keeps changing because it's not documented.

Comment: In v1.2.1,
`socket.request.connection.remoteAddress` and `socket.request.connection.remotePort` work for me.

However, I didn't see either of these properties listed when I tried:
`console.log(util.inspect(socket.request.connection, {showHidden: true, colors: true}));`

Why not?

Comment: Works in 1.3.4 also. Thanks

Comment: And what error is this, can you please explain?
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connection' of undefined
Is this the version issue? My socket version is 0.9.11
My code is:
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
var socketId = socket.id
    var clientIp = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress
    console.log(clientIp)

Comment: As of version `1.3.7`, this returns `::ffff:127.0.0.1`

Comment: In version 1.3.7  socket.request.connection.remoteAddress will work intermittently.  It will go undefined if the device stops responding.  I am using this to check whether the device reconnects as I track all my own sockets to keep them organized by the group that is connecting.  But I switched my code to use socket.handshake.address and it works great for this use.

Comment: Working for me perfectly.

Answer (score 62):

If you use an other server as reverse proxy all of the mentioned fields will contain localhost. The easiest workaround is to add headers for ip/port in the proxy server.

Example for nginx: 
add this after your `proxy_pass`:

```
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Real-Port $remote_port;
```

This will make the headers available in the socket.io node server:

```
var ip = socket.handshake.headers["x-real-ip"];
var port = socket.handshake.headers["x-real-port"];
```

Note that the header is internally converted to lower case.

If you are connecting the node server directly to the client,

```
var ip = socket.conn.remoteAddress;
```

works with socket.io version 1.4.6 for me.

Comment: This is the best solution,
the other answers do not work if nodejs is behind a proxy

Comment: @zuim You sir, are my hero!

Answer (score 23):

For latest socket.io version use

```
socket.request.connection.remoteAddress
```

For example:

```
var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.on('connection', function (client) {
  var client_ip_address = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
}
```

beware that the code below returns the Server's IP, not the Client's IP

```
var address = socket.handshake.address;
console.log('New connection from ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
```

Comment: i was about to try that handshake code, thanks for pointing out it's useless!!

Comment: What version is meant by "lastest socket.io version"? Please provide specific version.

Comment: Latest for July of 2014

Comment: What is the answer for Socket.io 3.0?

Answer (score 9):

Using the latest `1.0.6` version of `Socket.IO` and have my app deployed on `Heroku`, I get the client `IP` and `port` using the `headers` into the `socket handshake`:

```
var socketio = require('socket.io').listen(server);

socketio.on('connection', function(socket) {

  var sHeaders = socket.handshake.headers;
  console.info('[%s:%s] CONNECT', sHeaders['x-forwarded-for'], sHeaders['x-forwarded-port']);

}
```

Answer (score 9):

This works for the **2.3.0** version:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
   const ip = socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.conn.remoteAddress.split(":")[3];
   console.log(ip);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Version 0.7.7 of Socket.IO now claims to return the client's IP address. 
I've had success with:

```
var socket = io.listen(server);
socket.on('connection', function (client) {
  var ip_address = client.connection.remoteAddress;
}
```

Comment: its client.conn.remoteAddress; in the newer versions.

Answer (score 6):

Since socket.io 1.1.0, I use :

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('connection :', socket.request.connection._peername);
  // connection : { address: '192.168.1.86', family: 'IPv4', port: 52837 }
}
```

*Edit* : Note that this is not part of the official API, and therefore not guaranteed to work in future releases of socket.io.

Also see this relevant link :
[engine.io issue](https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io/issues/102)

Comment: Confirmed with 1.3.3 also.

Comment: @Rachael @ Codesleuth Thanks for the confirmation for the versions, it is much appreciated. I'm getting a few upvotes so i guess this is still valid, but I haven't tested myself.

Answer (score 5):

I have found that within the socket.handshake.headers there is a **forwarded for** address which doesn't appear on my local machine. And I was able to get the remote address using:

```
socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for']
```

This is in the server side and not client side.

Comment: Everything else I tried returned `::ffff:127.0.0.1` but this gave me the actual IP

Comment: love u, all other anwers give me loopback ip, only this header works!

Comment: This is the solution for the latest version [2.2.0]. Everything else returned server ip for me.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var endpoint = socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].address;
  console.log('Client connected from: ' + endpoint.address + ":" + endpoint.port);
});
```

Comment: This always returns `127.0.0.1` for me, not the client's IP (node.js runs on remote server).

Comment: try socket.request.connection.remoteAddress

Comment: Please provide Socket.io version you were using.

Answer (score 4):

Very easy.
First put

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

console.log(socket);
```

You will see all fields of socket. then use CTRL+F and search the word address.
Finally, when you find the field remoteAddress use dots to filter data.
in my case it is

```
console.log(socket.conn.remoteAddress);
```

Comment: Today I found the same solution in a similar matter!

Comment: This does not give the IP of the client endpoint. In my case it just returns the IP of the reverse proxy server.

Answer (score 4):

In version **v2.3.0**

this work for me :

```
socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(',')[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

I went through blog posts and even peoples answers to the question.

I tried `socket.handshake.address` and it worked but was prefixed with **::ffff:**

I had to use regex to remove that.

This works for version **4.0.1**

```
socket.conn.remoteAddress
```

Comment: This returns `::1` for me.

Comment: Yh that was what I said in the solution I gave. All you have to do is use regex or 3ven Javascript slicing to remove that part out of the info you want.

Comment: If you're behind a proxy, you must read `socket.handshake.headers['your_header_ip']`. For example, if you're behind CloudFlare, you should read `socket.handshake.headers['cf-connecting-ip']` to get the real user ip.

Answer (score 3):

From reading the socket.io source code it looks like the "listen" method takes arguments (server, options, fn) and if "server" is an instance of an HTTP/S server it will simply wrap it for you.

So you could presumably give it an empty server which listens for the 'connection' event and handles the socket remoteAddress; however, things might be very difficult if you need to associate that address with an actual socket.io Socket object.

```
var http = require('http')
  , io = require('socket.io');
io.listen(new http.Server().on('connection', function(sock) {
  console.log('Client connected from: ' + sock.remoteAddress);
}).listen(80));
```

Might be easier to submit a patch to socket.io wherein their own Socket object is extended with the remoteAddress property assigned at connection time...

Comment: This patch will most likely be included in the next release https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node/pull/286

Answer (score 3):

on `socket.io` 1.3.4 you have the following possibilities.

`socket.handshake.address`,

`socket.conn.remoteAddress` or

`socket.request.client._peername.address`

Answer (score 3):

In socket.io **2.0**: you can use:

`socket.conn.transport.socket._socket.remoteAddress`

works with `transports: ['websocket']`

Answer (score 2):

Welcome in 2019, where typescript slowly takes over the world.
Other answers are still perfectly valid. 
However, I just wanted to show you how you can set this up in a typed environment.

In case you haven't yet. You should first install some dependencies 
*(i.e. from the commandline: `npm install <dependency-goes-here> --save-dev`)*

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    ...
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.4",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    ...
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
```

I defined the imports using ES6 imports *(which you should enable in your `tsconfig.json` file first.)*

```
import * as SocketIO from "socket.io";
import * as http from "http";
import * as https from "https";
import * as express from "express";
```

Because I use typescript I have full typing now,
on everything I do with these objects.

So, obviously, first you need a http server:

```
const handler = express();

const httpServer = (useHttps) ?
  https.createServer(serverOptions, handler) :
  http.createServer(handler);
```

I guess you already did all that.
And you probably already added socket io to it:

```
const io = SocketIO(httpServer);
httpServer.listen(port, () => console.log("listening") );
io.on('connection', (socket) => onSocketIoConnection(socket));
```

Next, for the handling of new socket-io connections,
you can put the `SocketIO.Socket` type on its parameter.

```
function onSocketIoConnection(socket: SocketIO.Socket) {      
  // I usually create a custom kind of session object here.
  // then I pass this session object to the onMessage and onDisconnect methods.

  socket.on('message', (msg) => onMessage(...));
  socket.once('disconnect', (reason) => onDisconnect(...));
}
```

And then finally, because we have full typing now, we can easily retrieve the ip from our socket, without guessing:

```
const ip = socket.conn.remoteAddress;
console.log(`client ip: ${ip}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get your client's ip address (v 3.1.0):

---

```
// Current Client
const ip = socket.handshake.headers["x-forwarded-for"].split(",")[1].toString().substring(1, this.length);
// Server 
const ip2 = socket.handshake.headers["x-forwarded-for"].split(",")[0].toString();
```

---

And just to check if it works go to [geoplugin.net/json.gsp?ip=](http://geoplugin.net/json.gsp?ip=)
just make sure to switch the ip in the link. After you have done that it should give you the accurate location of the client which means that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

use `socket.request.connection.remoteAddress`

Comment: As of version `1.3.7`, this returns `::ffff:127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Latest version works with:

```
console.log(socket.handshake.address);
```

Comment: As of version `1.3.7`, this returns `::ffff:127.0.0.1`

Comment: similar 1.4.8 ::ffff:10.0.0.7

Comment: @dmr07 this is the IPv6 version. You can force the IPv4 by making the http server listen to `0.0.0.0`.
Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37378670/5138796

Comment: you can do console.log(socket.handshake.address.substring(7)) it will just print the ip 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

for my case

i change my

```
app.configure(socketio)
```

to

```
app.configure(socketio(function(io) {
 io.use(function (socket, next) {
   socket.feathers.clientIP = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
   next();
 });
}));
```

and i'm able to get ip like this

```
function checkIP() {
  return async context => {
    context.data.clientIP = context.params.clientIP
  }
}

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [
      checkIp()
    ]}
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In 1.3.5 :

```
var clientIP = socket.handshake.headers.host;
```

Comment: As of version `1.3.7`, this returns page url, not ip