# Get IP address on client side with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is it possible to get the client's ip address on clientside (within the browser) when using socket.io? Using pure Javascript alone can't get the client's IP address.

Comment: Refer this [socket.io: get client's IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6739366/500725)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way, unless you send the IP address over the socket from the server side.