# Not getting remote address while using proxy in socket.io

Tags: node.js, proxy, socket.io

In my socket.io code,

```
socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client){ 
    var ip = client.handshake.address.address;
    ..
}
```

ip always returns 127.0.0.1 and this is because the server sits behind a proxy.
How do I get remote address properly ?

Edit: I am using http-proxy

Comment: Checking if client.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || client.handshake.address.address; will work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

yes, this is working for me.

```
client.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || client.handshake.address.address;
```

I am properly getting the remote IP address and not 127.0.0.1

Comment: Confirmed: This is the first working solution since the last 10 answers I found by google.

Comment: this did not work for me. I am on a networked server/behind proxy, using 1.3.2

Comment: this one only work for socket 0.9. how about for version  >1.0?

Answer (score 7):

In version > 1.0, the syntax is similar:

```
socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who may come from Google, using NGINX: none of these worked for me, I followed the answer [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37474244/7163811) and modified my `proxy_pass`, to create a new header that node could then use. Don't forget to call `sudo systemctl restart nginx` after.