# Retrieving client IP address with Socket.io v1.0 and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

How does one retrieve the IP address of a socket.io connecting client?

This does not work in Socket.io v1.0: [Get the client's IP address in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458083/socket-io-get-clients-ip-address) .  It returns `undefined`.

I tried doing a `console.dir` of the `socket` object, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Any reason why you're using 1.0?

Comment: for long-term support, it seems that v1.0's API is slightly different from v0.9x..  v1.0's going to be released pretty soon?

Comment: socket.handshake returns `undefined`.

Comment: I can't even get the current repo installed, so it's still in flux I guess :)

Comment: I managed to get it installed, did you miss the `http+` header in npm?

Comment: No, I got hit with a dependency on a non-released version of `engine.io`, but apparently this happened because I was using the EU mirror of the NPM repo. I have it installed now, let me see...

Comment: I was using 1.0.4 and none of the answers I found here worked. I ended up going back to 0.9.16.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
socket.request.socket.remoteAddress
```

Comment: uh returns undefined, even when in the `io.on 'connection'` block..  I did a `console.dir` dump and there doesnt 'seem' to be any such IP information listed.

Comment: Hmm seems to work for me on the version posted on the repository. How did you install 1.0?

Comment: I did the normal NPM install, from the Git repo.

Comment: It returns an undefined.  btw, did you test client / server codes on same machine?

Comment: Yes, tried on same machine. When I try from a different machine it doesn't work for me either, but I also noticed that the transport being used is `polling`, which sounds strange. I think I would advice you to not use 1.0 until it's properly released :)

Comment: I resolved to sending the IP over via a client field.. is not really crucial though if its spoofed.