# Finding object properties from socket.io socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm playing around with socket.io and I'm trying trying to locate the different properties of the socket object on connection.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458083/socket-io-get-clients-ip-address/) which showed me the socket.request.connection.remoteAddress property, but when I do a console.log of the socket.request.connection object, the remoteAddress isn't listed as a property..

Why does console.log not list all the properties? Is there a better method to show an object?

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log(socket.request.connection.remoteAddress);   //works
    console.log(socket.request.connection); //Doesn't show remoteAddress or remotePort
    console.dir(socket.request.connection); //Same problem
});
```

Comment: perhaps console is skipping inherited or non-enumerable properties. Object.getOwnPropertyNames() will find hidden ones, for-in can find inherited ones. also, are you sure it's not listed? sometimes a lot of stuff flows by, overwhelming the screen line buffer of the console.

Comment: I saved the server output to a log and there was no remoteAddress property in the file. I've found some luck using Object.getOwnPropertyNames and for-in to list the keys but not the values. I'll keep investigating those, thanks.