# Logging how many connections an IP makes per given time, in socket.io/Express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

To prevent spamming of my app I was thinking of logging how many times a given Ip makes a connection, like refreshing the page or what ever, so if they exceed the amount of connections per say a second or a minute, I can log their ip, how could I achieve this in either Express or socket.io?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14631683/2980607) details how to get the request IP. You'll need to build out some middleware that will keep track of how many times a particular IP has requested your server.

Here's a rough in-memory approach

```
var ips = {};

app.enable('trust proxy')
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    if (ips[req.ip]) {
        var tracker = ips[req.ip];

        // If they've accessed less than a minute ago the same route increase count
        if (req.route === tracker.lastRoute && (new Date() - tracker.initReqTimestamp) < 60000) 
            tracker.count++;
        else { // Reset the counter
            tracker.count = 1
            tracker.initReqTimestamp = new Date();
            tracker.lastRoute = req.route;
        }

        ips[req.ip] = tracker;
    }
    else {
      ips[req.ip] = { 
        count: 1, 
        initReqTimestamp: new Date(),
        lastRoute: req.route
      };
    }

  if (ips[req.ip].count > connThreshold)
    // Do something

  else 
    return next(); // Continue to routes
});

// Put your Express Routes below this
```

As far as Socket.io, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24071662/2980607) details how to capture the socket client's IP. You can also write [socket.io middleware](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace) to keep track of how many connections an IP has made using a similar approach to the Express middleware example above.