# Why does NodeJS request() fail on localhost in flight mode, but not 127.0.0.1? (Windows 10)

Tags: node.js, dns, windows-10, requestjs

Given I already have a server up and running on localhost (see further down for an example), at a node command line *while online*, I get the following:

```
> var x = request('http://localhost:8080/test.html',
...               function(err) { if (err) console.log(err) })
undefined
>
```

I expect to get the above result all the time.

If I've switched to flight mode I get the following:

```
> var x = request('http://localhost:8080/test.html',
...               function(err) { if (err) console.log(err) })
undefined
> { Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT localhost:8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '8080' }
```

Trying this again with `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` works *whether or not* I'm in flight mode.

**Question**

Why does localhost not work? I can see it's something to do with Windows's DNS resolver.

**Setup for the client code above**

You need to install the [require](https://github.com/request/request) first:

```
C:\> npm install require
```

**Broader context**

I've boiled this down to the simplest I can. See [Why does web-component-tester time out in flight mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715485/why-does-web-component-tester-time-out-in-flight-mode) for the broader context.

**Example server**

The question isn't about the following server specifically, it's just a quick example. I think probably any local server would do, not just a NodeJS one. The problem is in the client code as detailed above.

Setup for the example server:

```
C:\> npm install connect serve-static
```

server.js:

```
var connect = require('connect')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080)
```

test.html:

```
<html>Really not important, but necessary for completeness</html>
```

Start the server:

```
C:\> node server.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install the Microsoft Loopback Adapter, as detailed below:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37718087/965952