# window.open on real time event (using socket.io) when my site open in more then one window

Tags: javascript, socket.io, dom-events

I having a real time feature in my website that open new window on socket.io event fired from the server side (*PHP/Laravel 5.1*).
The problem is if a user logged to my site and opened it in more than one tab/window - the new window.open fire multiple time, anyone know how can I prevent it?
my code look like this:

**the socket listener:**

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    if(typeof data.data !== "undefined"){
        lead_data = data.data;
    }else{
        lead_data = data;
    }
    if(typeof lead_data !== "undefined" && (lead_data.event_name == "new_call" || lead_data.event_name == "new_unsaved_call")){
        if(lead_data.user_id == uid){
            window.App.openCallWindow(data);
        }
    }
});
```

**and the `openCallWindow` function:**

```
openCallWindow : function(data){
    void(0);
    var lead_id = '';
    if(data && data.lead){
        lead_id = data.lead._id;
        window.open('/leads/callLead/'+lead_id,'new_lead'+Math.floor((Math.random()*999)+1), "height=800,width=1200" );
    }else if(typeof data.phone !== "undefined"){
        window.open('/leads/callLead/?phone='+data.phone,'new_lead'+Math.floor((Math.random()*999)+1), "height=800,width=1200" );
    }else{
        window.open('/leads/callLead/'+lead_id,'new_lead'+Math.floor((Math.random()*999)+1), "height=800,width=1200" );
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Client side active tab solution:**

You could call window.open only on, if the tab is active ( currently viewed ).
This could be done like [this](http://www.stepblogging.com/how-to-check-browser-tab-is-hidden-or-visible-using-jquery/):

```
function isTabActive(){
    var state; 

    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
        state = "visibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
        state = "mozVisibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        state = "msVisibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        state = "webkitVisibilityState";
    }
    return document[state] != "hidden";
}
```

**Client sided with cookies**

You could also use cookies to save if the popup is already open.
Cookies can be written and read with js.

**Server sided solution with socket.io**

If you have user accounts use them instead of the ip! Otherwise it will be buggy for multiple users with the same ip.

```
var alreadySend={};
io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
   if(!alreadySend.hasOwnProperty(socket.handshake.address))
   {
      socket.emit("create popup", "popup1");
      alreadySend[socket.handshake.address]=true;
   }
});
```

reset with

```
delete alreadySend[socket.handshake.address];
```

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458083/get-the-clients-ip-address-in-socket-io) you can find more detailed info about getting the ip with socket.io

Comment: thank you very much for the answer mate, but I still need to open the new window even if the window isn't active. is there's a way to validate how many windows of my website opened or check if the event fired already from another place?

Comment: I don't know if that is possible, but you could use the ip or username/userid of socket.io to only send the 'message'  to one connection per ip/user. The IP is in  `socket.handshake.address` and you could create an object like `messageSend[ip/userName]=true/false;` and then query before sending if this ip/user already got the message.

Comment: I'm quite new to socket.io, can you please give a code example? should I add it in the socket connection handler?

Comment: I extended my answer with two more solutions and example code!

Answer (score 0):

You can use state and access it through a function like

```
function isTabActive(){
    var state; 

    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
        state = "visibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
        state = "mozVisibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        state = "msVisibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        state = "webkitVisibilityState";
    }
    return document[state] != "hidden";
}
```