# How to get ip address from socket

Tags: node.js, socket.io, feathersjs

I have a nodeJS web service in based on feathersjs and feathers-socket.io
I need to know ip address of my clients in hook before. How can I do it?

Comment: Answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458083/get-the-clients-ip-address-in-socket-io

Comment: I need to have ip address in feathersjs hook before.

Comment: you can use this module as a middleware https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip

Comment: I added req.feathers.ip = req.ip to a middleware but it wasn't work. In other hand I use feathers-socket.io and I not see anything about IP in obj socket too. I used finally jquery get method $.getJSON getting ip address from jsonip.com and added it to params.query.